# Geolocator not giving accurate response in visual studio c++

Tags: visual-c++, geolocation

In a UWP C++ app in Visual Studio 2017 I have:

```
Geolocator^ geolocator = ref new Geolocator();
task<Geoposition^> geopositionTask = create_task(geolocator->GetGeopositionAsync());
geopositionTask.then([this](Geoposition^ place)
{       
    double la = place->Coordinate->Point->Position.Latitude;
    double lo = place->Coordinate->Point->Position.Longitude;
}
```

Can I increase the accuracy from the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure [DesiredAccuracy property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator#Properties) of the Geolocator object:

```
Geolocator^ geolocator = ref new Geolocator();
geolocator->DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy::High;
```